# Are there cross sections with an energy threshold? ($\sigma\sim \Theta(E-E_0)$ )

Tags: particle-physics, feynman-diagrams, symmetry-breaking, scattering-cross-section

Is it in principle possible to have a cross section $\sigma$ of a process, say  $a \bar{a}\to b \bar{b}$, which is proportional to the Heaviside function $\Theta(E-E_0)$, so this particular process gets triggered at some threshold energy $E_0$?

Is is e.g. possible via spontaneous symmetry breaking at a certain energy scale, so the process only becomes viable if a higher symmetry of the Lagrangian is restored?

Comment: well, there is the photoelectric effect , but little  to do with such symmetry expectations http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mod2.html

Comment: e.g in $e^+ e^- \rightarrow q \bar q$ need the $s$ channel energy for the electron-positron pair to be greater than the sum of the rest masses of the two outgoing quarks, otherwise they may not be produced.